# Android studio offline installation

Tags: android, android-studio

My windows XP development environment has no internet access. So I need to install Android Studio without internet connection. (Formerly I used 1-2 months IntelliJ IDEA 12 for android development)

**The steps I made:**

- I downloaded studio 0.2.x installation files from developer site (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).
- I downloaded JDK and installed.
- I already installed Android SDK package installer, downloaded API files and installed that files by using this package installer. (http://siddharthbarman.com/apd/)

I tried to create new project. I get "gradle" error. It seems like gradle is bundled inside studio but because of error exists, I downloaded gradle-1.6.zip from their website. (http://www.gradle.org/downloads) I added gradle\bin to my PATH environment variable.

Then I still get new errors that maven is missing. It seems like I need to download maven but I even don't know the version.

Can you write step by step that how many more programs / libraries should I download to get Hello world from Android studio and Android emulator ?

**Note:** I download files from a machine that has internet connection, copy them to flash disk and move to my development machine.

Comment: just try running the update.. go online by all means.. and how do you download anyway?

Comment: I download in another machine and move with flash disk.

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with your installation or something?.. and just try downloading everything here is to download :P

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: As you see from Siva's answer I need internet connection on that machine. So I gave up from Android Studio. I returned back to Intellij Idea.

Comment: Have you tried what says here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158034/how-to-setup-android-studio-to-work-completely-offline

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to download Maven. Android Studio only uses Gradle. However, the first time you build your project, you'd need to have a internet connection so that the Android Gradle plugin and all its dependencies are downloaded and cached on your local disk. With an active internet connection, do:

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ /path/to/gradle assembleDebug
```

Once that works, then you shouldn't need an internet connection.

Android Studio will eventually support such an offline mode.

Comment: I can download dependencies from another machine and copy them with flash disk. I can also install studio to a machine having internet connection, then I can copy relevant files/folders from machine with internet to machine without internet.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 0.4.0 now includes support for offline:

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released

"You can now open the Compiler > Gradle options and enable Offline mode, which will tell Gradle to ignore update-to-date checks"

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't work offline for creating new projects, so this is what I do and it works 100% offline!

1. Download Gradle and setup Environment variables
2. Create/Load project in Eclipse
3. File > Export
4. Select 'Generate Gradle build files'
5. Select project
6. Open AndroidStudio or IntelliJ13
7. Import project
8. Select 'Create project from existing sources'
9. Done!

But I preferred to use 'android create project' command, then setup 'build.gradle' file manually.