# How do I set up Android Studio to work completely offline?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have very slow bandwidth, so I'm trying to keep all the required files on the local machine to work with Android Studio completely offline. When I click on "New Project" it always tries to download a file named **gradle-1.6-bin.zip** which I downloaded and tried to install locally via the plugin manager but it gives me an error:

> fail to load plugin descriptor from file gradle-1.6-bin.zip

So what other files do I need to download and how do I install them properly to work offline with Android Studio?

Comment: It looks like this is a  common problem: (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58151&q=android%20studio%20offline&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) that hasn't been resolved yet... :/ I don't have AS installed on this machine but if I did I would test a machine connected to the internet and use a tool like wireshark to monitor any requests and pull all the requested files (and possibly set up a local http server and modify your hosts file to redirect connections to the Android Studio host to your localhost'ed server).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK guys I finally overcame this problem. Here is the solution:

1. Download `gradle-1.6-bin.zip` for offline use.
2. Paste it in the `C:\Users\username\.gradle` directory.
3. Open Android Studio and click on the "Create New Project" option and you will not get this error any more while offline.

   You might get some other errors like this:

   [image]

   Don't worry, just ignore it. Your project has been created.
4. So now click on "Import Project" and go to the path `C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects` and open your project and you are done.

Comment: Assume, dependency jars (gradle-x.y.z-all.zip), gradle-x.y.z.jar, gradle-x.y.z.pom are available with us. Could you please advise the path where to put them in android studio or sdk!

Answer (score 29):

Android Studio 0.4.0 now includes support for offline:

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released

"You can now open the Compiler > Gradle options and enable Offline mode, which will tell Gradle to ignore update-to-date checks"

**Updated Nov 2018:**
Now you can Open preferences, then search for "offline" and in the results select gradle and click "Offline work"

Comment: This checkbox is not working even in version 1.1, you can check here https://plus.google.com/u/0/115692564989237473252/posts/LGSbniYqj3Q

Comment: But you have to build it online once to be enable to do it offline laters

Comment: I got the idea to auto generate mipmap images of various resolutions of an image from this link. I have been looking for that for a ling time now. Thanks

Comment: How to open compiler at first place. Im not anle to find compiler

Comment: @ShirishHerwade - Open preferences, then search for "offline" and in the results select gradle and click "Offline work"

Answer (score 21):

**Android Studio Version < 3.6:**

For Windows:

```
File -> Settings ->Build, Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
```

For Mac OS:

```
Preferences ->Build, Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
```

Check/UnCheck `Offline work` checkbox as per your need.

**Android Studio Version >= 3.6:**

follow steps in the image:

[image]

Comment: Wow, I never knew there is this option. Only downside when i press this button is that i dont know if its turned off or on.

Comment: if it's turned on, the button will appear with a dark grey background, if not then the background will be clear. as shown in the image, its background is not dark grey and so it's not selected/turned-on

Answer (score 20):

I'm using Android Studio 0.5.4 (Mavericks).

> Preferences → Gradle → Global Gradle Settings → Offline work

Comment: Does that work for you?  It hasn't really done anything for me, and it looks like it isn't even really designed to let you work without internet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24019199/5457243

Answer (score 13):

Android Studio 1.3.1 has neither

`Gradle > Global Gradle settings > Offline work`

nor a

`Compiler`

menu. To access the compiler menu, go to :

`File > Settings > Build, Execution & Deployment > Compiler > Compiler`

and de-select `Configure on demand`

The above still uses data but is faster, I was able to load images and maps. However, in addition, if you want to be completely offline, you need to do the following:

```
 File -> Settings ->Build, Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle ->
```

check `Offline work`

Click the `OK` button.

For Android Studio 2.0  it is the same procedure.

Comment: Along with the offline mode, we have to change `distrbutionURI` to something like 

    distributionUrl=file:///home/foo/downloads/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Comment: Assume, dependency jars(gradle-x.y.z-all.zip), gradle-x.y.z.jar, gradle-x.y.z.pom are available with us. Could you please advise the path where to put them in android studio or sdk!

Answer (score 3):

Just as an assist if you go with Android Studio 0.4.x offline mode (because this thread is one of the main ones that google throws up when querying this issue).

From Alex Ruiz (Google+):

> If you specify dependency versions using "+" (e.g. 0.8.+) Gradle (not
>   Android Studio) will check that you have the latest version of such
>   dependency periodically (every 24 hours,) even in offline mode

You need to take the plus out.

Answer (score 3):

On Android 0.5.1 you can find the offline option in the File / Settings / Gradle (in the Project Settings section)/ Offline work

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it was removed before, I heard it was kinda buggy in `0.5.8` but in AS `0.5.9` the settings is there:

> Gradle > Global Gradle settings > Offline work

Answer (score 2):

For enabling Offline mode Android Studio Version Above 3.6, refer the following answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64180290/4324288

Answer (score 1):

You can enable from **File->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools-> Gradle-> Offline Work**.

Answer (score 1):

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Offline work

Answer (score 1):

for a complete offline android studio 3.5.0 installation - you need to download all these below components

**android studio, gradle, android gradle plugin and sdk.**

here is a detailed step by step Stackoverflow answer for the question

[how to install android studio full offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359851/how-to-install-android-studio-full-offline/60191428#60191428)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though gradle was not installed for me. Going to `Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper` and running `./gradlew tasks --debug` has resulted in it downloading.

Comment: This did indeed work, but my project wouldn't start building yet nonetheless. I chose the option to build it once with the online option (which popped up as an option in the console after build failed) and Android Studio started downloading and installing all the missing files. This did it for me, now building also works without an internet connection. I had to check the offline option again, however (File->Settings->Search for 'gradle' and check the offline option).