# How can I setup Android Studio so I can compile when offline (disconnected from the internet)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, offline-caching

I was working in androidstudio today and my builds started failing.  To my surprise, I had lost my internet connection and could no longer build my code.

build.gradle file contains the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'
    }
    tasks.withType(Compile) {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
...
```

So ... how do I reconfigure my development environment, change my build.gradle and do whatever else is necessary to allow android development offline.

**Note:**  Question edited to remove mavenLocal() from repositories, since it was added trying to solve this problem myself

Comment: Does the order the repos are listed in matter?

Comment: No, in fact the mavenLocal() was just added to try and resolve this problem without success -- I will remove it in the question since it may confuse the problem

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158034/how-to-setup-android-studio-to-work-completely-offline) answer help at all?

Comment: Nice link, but no real help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio 0.4.0 added this functionality:

From the release notes:

- [Studio now supports Gradle Offline mode](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio040released)

Comment: It still doesn't work if studio thinks that project is not synchronised. Command line gradle builds offline correctly

Answer (score 2):

Google is planning to bundle gradle with Android Studio, that will provide the ability to do builds offline. However, this will not be available until v0.5.0 preview release.  See [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58151) for details.

In the mean time, the current [workaround](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58151#c13) is to download your own gradle libs to make any builds offline.  You can do it as follows:

1. create a library cache command: "gradle build -g ./gradle-libs". 
   This will download all the required libraries in the folder "gradle-libs".
2. Then, in the offline compile: "gradle build --offline -g ./gradle-libs"

Answer (score 0):

1. List item

Definitely YES, you can always install Android Studio with all SDK packages & Tools on an Off-line PC. As I just did it myself.

Only thing U have to insure that you must have one PC with internet with Similar configuration as of Off-line PC(s).For example, if you have Win 7 64bit On-Line PC, then you should have Win 7 64 bit on Off-Line Pcs as well. But I have not tried extensively on 64 vs 32 bit PCs.

Once You have installed Android Bundle (available on android studio website), on both On-line and Off-line PCs, you downland all necessary files required to run the Android Studio properly on On-Line PC.

After that, compare the folder inside sdk folder: "C:\user\name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk " available on both PCs (On-Line & Off-Line). And where ever you feel that some files are missing copy that folder from On-Line PC and paste in Off-Line Pc.Especially, you need to do this for folder : 'extras', 'tool' & 'system-images'.

After this, just ENJOY!!!