# Does Android studio need internet connection to build project

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android studio version 0.4.2 and gradle version 1.9. I have successfully installed Studio and have created multiple projects. Today when I launched Studio **without internet connection**,

I got this error message:

> "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing,
>   debugging) will not work properly" and the Event Log window shows
>   "Failed to refresh Gradle project < Project Name >. Connection timed
>   out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the
>   proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle."

I need to know if internet connection is mandatory for building projects using gradle.

I think gradle checks for latest version on internet and throws Connection time out error. If so, is there any workaround to disable that.

Comment: Any solution? I tried all of the below, but none of them helped and I have a stable a good Internet connection.

Comment: I am using android studio and have a stable internet connection,so it work properly but today I have a little bit slow connection and I am facing the same error that gradle sync failed.So I think it needs a stable connection to work properly.without gradle you can perform other functions but cannot be able to run the app on emulator.

Answer (score 30):

Currently Android Studio's Gradle implementation **requires** a fast stable network connection.  For whatever reason, the developers have decided to force this requirement on users at this time.  There is a setting that you should be able to use to utilize a local gradle installation, but it doesn't hold.  The developers know about both the network requirement and the broken switch, but are currently prioritizing other functionality.  They *may* remove that requirement in the 1.0 or post 1.0 time frame.

[see: https://plus.google.com/u/0/115692564989237473252/posts/LGSbniYqj3Q ]

Gradle's **offline** mode, isn't.  It should be properly named *cached* mode. All that switch does is tell gradle to not try to go online and instead utilize cached copies of the various networked resources.  Unfortunately that assumes that you have had (and will have again) a network connection, preferably a fast stable one.  Using Android Studio (last version tested 0.5.9) with a slow/unstable network results in watching Android Studio process Gradle ( and Maven ) processes usually for 2-5 minutes, sometimes for 10 minutes or more.  Also at seemingly random times when coding the IDE will lock up and the cause usually involves one or more Gradle processes that have spun up.

As a comparison, using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 Community edition (the IDE that Android Studio is based on) I compared a default "Hello Android" IDE generated program using the Android Gradle wizard (substantially similar to the only one in Android Studio) and the Ant based Android wizard.  The results were as expected.  The gradle based project experienced the same painful lock up and lag that projects in Android Studio exhibited.  The ant based Android project was near instantaneous.  No appreciable delay once the project was created and opened.  Coding caused no random lockups.  Testing was done on a Windows 8.1 update1 Pro machine with a dual Athlon x2 processor, 6GB RAM, and a 6Mb/0.75Mb DSL connection.  I believe that last part is most likely the issue.

Unfortunately until Android Studio removes the network requirement I feel it will be unusable to a large number of developers.  That's a shame because otherwise it looks to be a marked improvement over the existing Eclipse based development environment.

Comment: I'm installing Android Studio because I've heard that new projects should use it, but are you saying that without an internet connection I won't be able to do anything?  That is to say, if I install Android Studio am I stuck with Gradle or is there any alternative?

Comment: honestly, it is this kind of B.S. that encourages rage quit

Comment: Android studio is a rollback from eclipse days!!! I hope google care more about developers...

Comment: Assume, dependency jars(gradle-x.y.z-all.zip), gradle-x.y.z.jar, gradle-x.y.z.pom are available with us. Could you please advise the path where to put them in android studio or sdk!

Answer (score 11):

For me, I had to check and then **uncheck** the box in

> Preferences->Gradle->Offline work.

Then I got back online.

Answer (score 9):

You can download the gradle distribution locally and build the project again.

To do this, edit your `gradle-wrapper.properties` under `gradle-> wrapper` in your Android project.

Edit the

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

to

> distributionUrl=file:///home/foo/downloads/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

So just download the file from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip) as mentioned in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Comment: i do so. but this error is still yet. (Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.)   . what can i do?

Comment: just make sure the file that you downloaded exists by putting the path `file:///home/foo/d..../gradle-2.2.1-all.zip` in a browser. I just fixed a typo in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's an offline mode preference in Preferences > Compiler > Gradle. If you already have your dependencies downloaded, this will generally work for you.

Comment: I have already tried that (Compiler > Gradle > checked Offline Mode option) but no use.

Comment: Once you have to connect with internet to download dependencies and gradle distribution, if not there in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio version 1.5.1 I could solve this error by following steps :

1) Go to file -> Settings -> HTTP Proxy -> & select Auto detect proxy settings.
2) After that you may get Dialog to accept or reject certificate
3) Select Accept.

That's it.

Comment: what error are you getting? After following the steps given in my answer you should not get error of proxy. OR You can try to set proxy manually also.

Comment: i download gradle 2.12 , and path it manually like @Neo as above. but it shows this error (Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.). how can i set proxy manually?

Comment: please refer this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31810550/1374918) if you didn't set your gradle-wrapper.properties file.