# Gradle says that build failed because of volley library

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, android-volley

Today when I run my app on android studio has turned out this error:

```
 Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Could not resolve com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+.
 Required by:
     NewOferSalud:app:unspecified
  > Failed to list versions for com.mcxiaoke.volley:library.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > peer not authenticated
```

I do not understand what happened because I have not touched anything volleyball and previously worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.
keep it connected to internet while compiling.
Or download the jar file.
For more reference, see this.
[Does Android studio need internet connection to build project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746087/does-android-studio-need-internet-connection-to-build-project)