# Android Studio gradle couldn't sync

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I have upgraded android studio from 1.4 to 2.1 and my existing projects couldn't sync with the below gradle error

```
Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.
```

I am not using any proxy and I have made sure not to use proxy from the android studio IDE. but it keeps on coming with the same error and no idea how to fix this.

I am stack on this and would appreciate any one who could shade some light on this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746087/does-android-studio-need-internet-connection-to-build-project

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes. I am using 2.1.2