# Why Android Studio gradle sync lasts more than 10 minutes when I added local source dependency (no need to download)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependency-management

I just created a fresh new Android application from what Android Studio proposes (1 simple activity, no dependencies, it builds and installs and runs OK).

Then I downloaded some big fat library that comes as source code from sourceforge (to be precise: it's [OpenCV for Android v. 4.1.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.1.2/opencv-4.1.2-android-sdk.zip/download)).

I added that library as new module to my project by: File -> New -> Import module and I've chosen that library source code to be added. It worked and then gradle sync. has automatically started.
It lasts for 10 minutes already and it does not seem to finish soon. **Why is that when nothing should be downloaded?** [If some payload must have been downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636707/what-is-gradle-sync-in-android-studio/44077149#44077149) I'd understand, but here?

EDIT: It finished with success but it lased 14 minutes! Why so long?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you aren't downloading anything in particular, try enabling the Offline Work for Gradne Sync.

```
Go > File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Gradle
```

Toggle `'Offline Work'` mode