# Build Gradle require internet connection

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My `Android studio` application always asks to keep internet connected during build Gradle otherwise it does not run Gradle

**How can i disable it and use stable version android-studio without internet?**

Comment: hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746087/does-android-studio-need-internet-connection-to-build-project

Answer (score 4):

Gradle needs an internet connection to download the dependencies that you specify.
Once it downloads everything, it can put them in memory so that you can work offline.

To do this, you need to go to Files->Settings (For Mac: Android Studio-> Settings...).

Then, you go to Gradle and you check "Offline work"
[image]

You can now build your project without internet.

**CAUTION**: if you change or add dependencies, you will need internet again.
Hope that helps

Comment: I hate gradle!  It just wastes time!. Can't Google come up with a new solution? Maybe build a new technology from scratch?

Comment: i hope google just ditch gradle and using build system like on golang