# how to install android studio full offline

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to install android studio on many PCs. Is there any way to install android studio latest version offline by downloading all the offline files just once?
Most of the PCs are running windows 8.1 / 8 / 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely YES, you can always install Android Studio with all SDK packages & Tools on an Off-line PC. As I just did it myself.

Only thing U have to insure that you must have one PC with internet with Similar configuration as of Off-line PC(s). For example, if you have Win 7 64 bits On-Line PC, then you should have Win 7 64 bit on Off-Line PC as well. But I have not tried extensively on 64 vs 32 bit PCs.

Once You have installed Android Bundle (available on android studio website), on both On-line and Off-line PCs, you download all necessary files required to run the Android Studio properly on On-Line PC.

After that, compare the folder inside sdk folder: "C:\user\name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk " available on both PCs (On-Line & Off-Line). And where ever you feel that some files are missing copy that folder from On-Line PC and paste in Off-Line PC. Especially, you need to do this for folder : 'extras', 'tool' & 'system-images'.

After this, just ENJOY!!!

Comment: I think they removed the bundle option. You can only download Android Studio now.

Comment: Does this still work, I am planning to do it?

Answer (score 8):

in response to "The following SDK component was not installed: build-tools-21.1.1"

- download build-tools 21.1.1 from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.1-windows.zip
- unzip it under your sdk /build-tools folder (e.g. %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\ for Windows)
- you'll get then /build-tools/android-5.0/ right beside /build-tools/21.1.2/
- restart Android Studio

NB: all credit goes to the community http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82789#c5

Answer (score 4):

## Android studio 3.5.0 Offline installation - Completely Offline

*First I would like to inform you, that the best and secure way is to find good internet connection and connect your computer and simply wait android studio doing all of these above steps for you.but if you are like me with limited internet access or for some reason if you can't connect your computer at all and you are using windows 7, 8 and 10 64bit machine, here is a detailed steps to download all required components at once in another computer with internet and install on your computer **COMPLETELY OFFLINE**.*

### Download Files

- android studio 3.5.0 - [download link](https://getintopc.com/softwares/development/android-studio-2019-free-download/)
- android-sdk -[download link](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IR1AG2I5E6i2vNrtCkIpINSVIXArR_yx&export=download)
- gradle 5.4.1 - [download link](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip)
- android gradle plugin 3.5.0

  At the time of writing this, the official website developer.android.com only provide android gradle plugin 3.5.0-beta 01 and the required version by android studio 3.5.0 is not the beta version but android gradle plugin 3.5.0 - so you have to recursively download every required files and folders using wget from this site ([link](https://nexus.xebialabs.com/)).

In order to do that, first download wget ([download link](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)) copy it to c:\ location and add it to the [windows path environment variable](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/).

download the .bat file ([android gradle plugin downloader](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=80180673566481714255))

After that select and right click the download.bat file and run it as an administrator.   The batch command will use wget to download and construct all files and folder for android-gradle-plugin 3.5.0

wait for the download to complete....

And follow these below steps :

#### 1 - unzip the android sdk to this below location

%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local\Android/Sdk

[image]

#### 2 - install android studio 3.5.0 and let android studio try to build your created project and close it when it gives you an error.

[image]

#### 3 - copy gradle 5.4.1.zip to

%USERPROFILE%/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.4.1-all/3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx/
if the folder didn't exist create it.

[image]

#### 4 - copy all folders from C:\android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0\nexus.xebialabs.com\nexus\content\repositories\public

[image]

and paste it to %USERPROFILE%/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0
create the folder android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0 if it didn't exist.

[image]

#### 5 - finally, to tell the Android build system to use the offline android gradle plugin, you need to create a script, as described below.

Create an empty text file with the following path and file name:
windows won't allow to create init.d folder you have to do it from command line, so within the .gradle folder press shift + right click - > click open command_window_here and type mkdir init.d

"%USERPROFILE%/.gradle/init.d/offline.gradle/"

[image]

then from within the init.d folder - right click > hover over new > click text document. copy and paste below script and save as the file as offline.gradle

```
    def reposDir = new File(System.properties['user.home'], ".android/manual-offline-m2")

    def repos = new ArrayList()  

    reposDir.eachDir {repos.add(it) }  

    repos.sort()  

    allprojects {  

      buildscript {  

        repositories {  

          for (repo in repos) {  

            maven {  

              name = "injected_offline_${repo.name}"  

              url = repo.toURI().toURL()  

            } 
          } 
        } 
      }  
      repositories {  

        for (repo in repos) {  

          maven {  

            name = "injected_offline_${repo.name}"  

            url = repo.toURI().toURL()
          }
        } 
      }
    }
```

Save the text file.

[image]

#### 6 - run Android studio

To make sure your are running offline, comment these below lines with "//" in build.gradle file, as shown below.

```
   

        buildscript {
        repositories {
            // Hide these repositories to test your build against
            // the offline components. You can include them again after
            // you've confirmed that your project builds ‘offline’.
            // google()
            // jcenter()
        }
        ...
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            // google()
            // jcenter()
        }
        ...

}
```

By now, your offline android studio should work.

Comment: How/where did you get the download.bat file (android gradle plugin downloader)?  I'm interested in doing something similar for AS 3.6, wondering if I can just change the version in the .bat file.
Thanks for the detailed post!

Comment: you welcome Ben, just download wget add it the path. and do this from the command line `wget --continue --directory-prefix="c:\android-gradle-plugin" --no-check-certificate --no-parent --recursive --timestamping "https://nexus.xebialabs.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/"` , it may take  long time to recursively download all folder but i guess it will include everything you want for android studio 3.6

Answer (score 3):

Android studio latest version offline by downloading all the offline files only one time then you have to download " All Android Studio Packages " and link is:
 - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: After installation when i run Android Studio, getting error: "The following SDK component was not installed: build-tools-21.1.1"

Answer (score 2):

Google has a special GDG Dev Kit Pilot that comes with everything needed to install Android Studio offline. It's basically 4 DVDs that contain the entire Android Website, including Android SDKs, Material Design docs, tutorial videos and a ton of other useful dev material.

It's available completely free through your nearest [Google Developers Group](https://developers.google.com/groups/directory/),
 Google Student Ambassador, or
you can download the entire kit here: 
[GDG Dev Kit Pilot ReadMe](https://sites.google.com/site/gdgdevkitpilotreadme/home/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

You may download the Android Studio "Bundle" that contains both the IDE and the SDK. You may then install it on as many computers as you want.

The link is: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I have downloaded that bundle: "android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe" and installed. But after installation when i run the file it show me error "The following SDK component was not installed: build-tools-21.1.1".

Answer (score 0):

This is the common link for all versions of Android Studio depending on Platforms.
Also options like with SDK or without SDK can be choosen.
All Downloads are offline Installers.
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

This link below is latest for Windows x64 as on 21Feb2017.
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.2.3.0/android-studio-bundle-145.3537739-windows.exe

Use Andorid Studio official site for downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Download android studio `3.5.0` `beta 1` and offline components.