# how to install android studio 2.0 offline complete

Tags: java, android, android-studio, torrent

how i can install android studio complete offline.
because my internet is slow. 
thanks in advance.

I need to install android studio in many pc. So, i wish if there is any way to install android studio lattest version offline by downloading all the offline file just once time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install android studio full offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359851/how-to-install-android-studio-full-offline)

Comment: not working for me that one thanks for response