# Forticlient vs Android

Tags: antivirus, appcompatactivity

My computer has a Fortinet client. Is it the reason that I didn't download repository? For example, when I open an empty project I get an error about `AppCompatActivity`

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA3hm.jpg)

> Blockquote
>    ERROR:
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
>   Required by:
>       project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: i guess it is a proxy problem

Comment: Should i do this ? I can copy all files from my other computer.Should i do ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33383940/6056459

Comment: ıt worked but ı got another error about emulator.