# I have installed Android Studio and my gradle is downloading files from last 3 hours

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new to the Android Studio. I installed Android Studio  when I try to build the new project it keeps on downloading some files for hours and hours. It shows this thing:

[image: progress bar]

Comment: We cannot see that thing...

Comment: May be Due to Network Problem its taking too much time.. And also if you are using Android Studio You need to have Ram More than 4+gb.. for better performance .. you problem seems with network..

Comment: Check for your internet speed or download and install android studio offline, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359851/how-to-install-android-studio-full-offline

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, I usually restart my PC after trying to rebuild/clean, close and reopen the project.

Similar issues may occur also while waiting for the emulator to load or the APK to be installed on it as well.

However, there are some updates that may really take a while to complete just like when you update many SDK standalone elements, for instance.