# Installing ALL android studio offline

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a PC which is not connected to Internet. I want to download every thing related to android studio (SDK, plugins support) any thing that I might need including different version of (API, SDK, plugins supports etc).
I already tried, didnt work, first I installed the studio then copied SDK. But I faced many problems, every time I solve one anther one comes. 
sample of errors (constraint-layout:1.1.3) not found runner not found etc. 
I need a smooth direct way to do thay. Any one can help

Comment: Developing on a machine that is not connected to internet at all will cause you an enormous amount of problems. And don't think about downloading all existing librairies, because it's obviously impossible (and you never know which one you will need ...)

Answer (score 1):

for Complete offline android studio installation - you need to download all these below components

**android studio, gradle, android gradle plugin and sdk.**

here is a detailed step by step answer for the question

[how to install android studio full offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359851/how-to-install-android-studio-full-offline/60191428#60191428)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install android studio offline

Than i would suggest you to go with android studio older version

In older version you install jdk and android studio separately, but in the latest version of android studio the jdk is included in android studio itself there is no external requirement of jdk , but for the latest version you must have Internet connectivity because there is alot of inbuild package which can only be installed if you have Internet connection .

If any how you manage to install it ofline , than there is more chance of getting error during build.

So if you want a clean installation and bug free coding please go for online installation .

[Download for Windows Download Android Studio and SDK tools  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

[Download for mac Download Android Studio and SDK tools  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

[Android Studio download archives | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

Download a version of android studio from above google site.

You can download the just android studio if you already have android sdk installed. ( You have to setup path manually for the Android Studio).

Or you can download android studio bundled with sdk and tools.( I recommend this.)

Comment: Which version from archive I should  use ? I already downloaded the stduio I even copied every thing from a working PC (entire studio folder and entire SDK) still not working

Comment: I think just can install Android Studio, and SDK offline without internet, maybe use Android Studio 3.0 . With Gradle you can not implement library like `compile com.google` maybe need implement lib with JAR file