# Android studio can't run when connected to internet

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I run on anything it just says:

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

But once I disconnect from the internet it starts working. Otherwise it just keeps saying it forever. I already waited like 15m
I already ticked offline in Settings > Gradle and also used the deamon and parallel in gradle.properties. its actually pretty fast when im not connected to the internet.

and my net is incredibly awful, could it be that? if yes is there anything i can do myself (download something myself) so it can work offline?

and also my problem is diffrent than the others, for others it takes long which gets fixed by gradle.properties but mine is about the internet connection!

and also Im running Windows 8 x64!

Comment: Are there any other heavy processes using the internet in your system? I might be wrong here but its possible that when connected to internet your whole system becomes slower in turn making android studio slower. So I would try closing any other **network** processes.

Comment: There are none, and after i force stop android studio i can run eclipse projects in a blink! and just to make sure im doing it right, how can i check and close network processes?

Comment: On windows, **start** and search for **Resource Monitor**, once opened, select the **Network** tab, here you can see all and stop network processes.

Comment: Nothing special there!

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158034/how-to-setup-android-studio-to-work-completely-offline) will help you then.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with gradle?i manually downloaded and extracted gradle 2.1.1 to C:\Users\NAME\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all nothing's changed!

Comment: Thanks YourJavaMinoin, i will try that! and also. replugging my nexus 4 used as thether (with debugign on but drivers not installed, my main device is note 4 and i just have my nexus 4 waiting for sale!) helps! even if i enable tether again! i will also try to tether with my note 4

Comment: it still doesn't work :|

Comment: I got this this time: Gradle exec failed cause: software casue connection abort: recv failed

Comment: Sorry for posting so many comments but using a proxy helped!

Comment: You can add that as your answer and mark it as correct.