# Android studio: com.android. tools.build:gradle3.5.3 available for offline mode

Tags: android-studio

Please how do I resolve this android studio error: no cache version of com.android. tools.build:gradle3.5.3 available for offline mode

Comment: looks like you workspace gradle is offline. go to preferences, build tools , gradle and check wether you have enable gradle to work online. for newer android studio, there is no such feature

Comment: All right, thanks. But I prefer working offline, how do I resolve it?

Comment: @buikedaniel hope this helps [How do I set up Android Studio to work completely offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158034/how-do-i-set-up-android-studio-to-work-completely-offline)